# map.setMyLocationEnabled(true); is not working

Tags: android, google-maps, android-location

I have just started working on a android project and is using the Google Map API.

I am able to fetch the map on my app but when i try to enable the current location with `map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);`, the app says unfortunately app has stopped working.

When I removed the line `map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);` then it worked fine. Can anyone please help me to get the current location button enabled.

Comment: Please see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this), then [edit] your question to include the logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using android 6.0 or above, you should:

1. Make sure you added `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` in your `AndroidManifest` file.
2. You need to check permission at run-time in this link: [Requesting Permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

> Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app. This approach streamlines the app install process, since the user does not need to grant permissions when they install or update the app. It also gives the user more control over the app's functionality;

If you want an easy-to-use library for permission checking, I suggest [Permission Dispatcher](https://github.com/hotchemi/PermissionsDispatcher).

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#setMyLocationEnabled(boolean)), you need to have requested permission for either `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` or `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`.

My guess is you haven't and your app is throwing a `SecurityException`.