# SetMyLocationEnabled not working in android Map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, location, fusedlocationproviderapi

Can Anyone help me Please.I dont know what happened.My location is working..

I have added the Api key and everything.I know the code show give my current location it was so far but suddenly its not>??

Can any one help please

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private final static int MY_PERMISSION_FINE_LOCATION = 101;
ZoomControls zoom;
Button markBt;
Button geoLocationBt;
Button satView;
Button clear;
Double myLatitude = null;
Double myLongitude = null;
private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
private LocationRequest locationRequest;
protected static final String TAG = "MapsActvity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();

    locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    locationRequest.setInterval(15 * 1000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    //set to balanced power accuracy on real device


}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("from onMapClick"));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        }
    });
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    } else {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSION_FINE_LOCATION);
        }
    }


}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSION_FINE_LOCATION:
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This app requires location permissions to be granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    requestLocationUpdates();
}

private void requestLocationUpdates() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
    }

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Connection Suspended");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Connection Failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    myLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    myLongitude = location.getLongitude();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    googleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, this);
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        requestLocationUpdates();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    googleApiClient.disconnect();
}
```

}

Comment: Make sure that you have fine location permissions in your manifest. You can learn more about it [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/location#location_permissions). You can also check in the next step in the documentation on how to properly add or implement the `setMyLocationEnabled(true)` in you code. For more information about this issue, check these related SO questions: [map.setMyLocationEnabled(true); is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39395739) and [map.setmylocationenabled(true) not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34608517)

Comment: Added in manifest and also i have added map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opps .....My GPS was not working...thats the problem